# Cant get a smart contract address balance with standard address(this).balance;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Im newbee with everything connected to solidity and smart contracts. Maybe im just missing something really obvious, but anyway.
So, i have parity running locally in development chain mode.
I have a pretty simple smart contract, just a modified Hello World.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract HelloWorld {
  function getContractAddress() public returns (address) {
    return address(this);
  }

  function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return address(this).balance;
  }
}
```

I call functions and deploy smart contract in rails console now, i use gem ethereum, so for me it looks like  (i use dev chain, so it takes the default dev account

```
contract = Ethereum::Contract.create(file: "/home/work/greeter.sol")
contract.deploy_and_wait
```

As an output for `deploy` command i see a smart contract address.
As an output for `contract.call.get_contract_address` i see a valid address
And when i call `contract.call.get_contract_balance` i receive error `IOError: VM execution`, in the corresponding logs its

```
I, [2020-04-26T21:32:57.469694 #7580]  INFO -- : Sending {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"to":"0x0faf2f31ab165b55f42e55c8065c0ec7170a0d45","from":"0x00a329c0648769a73afac7f9381e08fb43dbea72","data":"0x6f9fb98a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","gas":"0x3d0900","gasPrice":"0x51f4d5c00"},"latest"],"id":1}
I, [2020-04-26T21:32:57.470292 #7580]  INFO -- : Received {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32015,"message":"VM execution error.","data":"Bad instruction 47"},"id":1}
```

Comment: How are you testing the contracts? ganache, private testnet. Make sure you have enabled newer opcodes in the genesis file.